# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null

Tags: java, android, picasso

When I am passing image url to Picasso then it shows me error "Target must not be null". When I fetch image from url using Picasso then it shows me error. Even my id assigned to image is correct. At last I replaced the image url with static image, though I receive error as same.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView user_profile_pic,img2;
private ImageView like_button,dislike_button,location_button,refresh;

private ArrayList<String> al;
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
private int i;

private SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);


    //Setting
    user_profile_pic=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
    img2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);

    //Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/596282530652753921/bPf8NmOs.jpg").into(user_profile_pic);

    //Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(android.R.drawable.btn_star).into(img);


    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/596282530652753921/bPf8NmOs.jpg")
            .placeholder(android.R.drawable.btn_star)
            .error(android.R.drawable.btn_star)
           .into(img2);


    flingContainer = (SwipeFlingAdapterView) findViewById(R.id.frame);

    al = new ArrayList<>();
    al.add("php");
    al.add("c");
    al.add("python");
    al.add("java");
    al.add("html");
    al.add("c++");
    al.add("css");
    al.add("javascript");

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.custom_user_details, R.id.helloText, al );

    flingContainer.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    flingContainer.setFlingListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.onFlingListener() {
        @Override
        public void removeFirstObjectInAdapter() {

            Log.d("LIST", "removed object!");
            al.remove(0);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLeftCardExit(Object dataObject) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Left !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRightCardExit(Object dataObject) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Right !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdapterAboutToEmpty(int itemsInAdapter) {

            al.add("XML ".concat(String.valueOf(i)));
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.d("LIST", "notified");
            i++;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(float scrollProgressPercent) {

            try
            {
                View view = flingContainer.getSelectedView();
                view.findViewById(R.id.item_swipe_right_indicator).setAlpha(scrollProgressPercent < 0 ? -scrollProgressPercent : 0);
                view.findViewById(R.id.item_swipe_left_indicator).setAlpha(scrollProgressPercent > 0 ? scrollProgressPercent : 0);
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Log.e("tag", "NullPointerException" + e);
            }

        }
    });

    //flingContainer.getTopCardListener().selectRight(); To remove view from right side while pressing button

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_screen, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

And this is what my xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="80">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/img2"
                android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Vimal, "
                    android:id="@+id/helloText"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="23"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_dialog"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                        android:gravity="center"/>

                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_dialog"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>




    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/item_swipe_left_indicator"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#A5F" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/item_swipe_right_indicator"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#5AF" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: android.R.drawable.btn_star ?

Comment: Yup.. @Rustam Using by default image of android.

Comment: img2  is the target so did you checked it for null?

Comment: are you using correct layout? if so add you activity code.

Comment: just clean and run again

Comment: Still facing problem... @Rustam

Comment: Where is the stack trace? and the indication of which line is throwing the exception?

Answer (score 0):

`img2` is null, and you're passing that into the `into` function.

Add a null check after `img2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);` to check when it stops being null or whether it stays null while you're testing, or just to confirm that it is null.

Check your layout ID's and make sure they're right for ALL the configurations, and make sure you have `@+id/img2` specified .

Comment: I tried to check for the null using below code:  if (img2==null)
        {
            img2.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star);
        }

        else
        {
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/596282530652753921/bPf8NmOs.jpg")
                    .placeholder(android.R.drawable.btn_star)
                    .error(android.R.drawable.btn_star)
                    .into(img2);

        }

Comment: Then I received this error in logcat: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: your above comment clearly indicate your `img2` is `null`

Comment: @VimalDiwani You're trying to call a the function `setImageResource()` after making sure img2 is null... Of course you're getting that error! The point is to only do it if it is NOT null. If it's null then you need to check your ID's and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure load the correct layout ? because you have R.id.profile_image in Java file, but i didn't found that id in your xml file.

Comment: he is using `R.id.img2` not `R.id.profile_image` in picasso.load();

Comment: yes, i know, but  i ask that he sure he load the correct layout ? because in his java code there is :  user_profile_pic=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profile_image); and in his xml it's doesn't include that id, even there is id img2 .

Answer (score 0):

try to change it as..

```
Picasso.with(MainScreen.this).load("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/596282530652753921/bPf8NmOs.jpg")
            .placeholder(android.R.drawable.btn_star)
            .error(android.R.drawable.btn_star)
           .into(img2);
```

also make sure that you are using the `activity_main_screen.xml` layout and check the id if img2 there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't download image from **https** using Picasso library.
you can use [this](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library.

Comment: I see it works even when you use `https` protocol, but it did not work when any URL redirect to another `https` URL.